# Python: Calling function from command line using argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I am new to python. I am trying to implement a simple program that uses arguments to call various functions.

```
def function1(releaseid,path)
...

def function2(versionid)
...
```

Lets say those functions are in a.py , I would like to call those functions in other script called b.py.

I want to call this way:

```
python --function  function1 --version 10.23.401-Jun --path /test/common/releases
python --function  function2 --version 10.23.401-Jun
```

How could we handle this to call `function1` , `function2` in a.py with required arguments?   i found that we can handle this with argparse module . Can you please share some example?

Comment: I have an idea....maybe you can call functions dynamically inside Python like this  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018953/whats-the-way-to-call-a-function-dynamically-in-python

Comment: and pass the parameters in a String comma separated  and then split

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use argparse, have a look on https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html

In the simpliest form it would be like

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--function", help="<description>",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.function == "function1":
    function1()
elif args.function == "function2":
    function2()
```

However, there are much better third-party libraries for building cli interfaces, for example https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

Comment: Hi Mikhail, How can we validate arguments of a function... ? How can you call the function with arguments ?

Comment: But you depends using If....and how pass the Parameters?....Look have not the Same Q Parameters